# How to read from a text file when adding firewall rules using new-netfirewallrule

Tags: powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting, windows-firewall

I am trying to create a script to read from a text file to which I would like to add firewall rules to each server on a line by line basis.

It doesn't seem like it is reading it line by line, and it looks to only take the first line that I put in.

```
$ComputersPath = "C:\temp\kofaxcomputers.txt"

Get-Content $ComputersPath | ForEach {

if ($ComputersPath -ne $null) {

        New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Kofax - KTM" -Direction Inbound -RemoteAddress Any -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 2424
        Write-Host "$_ installed" -ForegroundColor Green;
        } else {
        Write-Host "$_ failed" -ForegroundColor Red;
        }}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to learn PowerShell. Here the line `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Kofax - KTM" -Direction Inbound -RemoteAddress Any -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 2424` actually doesn't have anything dynamic to be in a foreach loop, can you tell us what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to add an inbound firewall rule I created called "Kofax - KTM" to a windows server 2012.  So I utilize a text based document and read the values from there, line by line.

Comment: what are the values in the text file ?

Comment: The values are just server names in the text file.  I just tried your script and it works.  Although it looks like it will keep adding the rule to the server even if it already has the same rule.

Comment: do a `Get-NetFirewallRule` first, then decide based on the exiting rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a firewall rule in a bunch of computers,

- Have a list of computer in you text file(make sure there are no trailing spaces)
- Read all the computers from the text file and save it in  a variable.
- Use `Invoke-command` to execute the `New-NetFireWallRule` on all those computers.

  ```
   $Computers = get-Content -Path "C:\temp\kofaxcomputers.txt"

   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers -ScriptBlock {
       New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Kofax - KTM" -Direction Inbound -RemoteAddress Any -Action Allow -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 2424
   }
  ```